# Reply to an email is missing mail header information

Tags: vba, outlook

I have written code to reply to an email in certain format.

The result is missing informaation for the last received email in the Html body (From, sent, to, cc, subject. I'm not sure if this is called the mail header).

If I click on the 'reply' button, this info would have been auto-generated ahead of the last email, while above it would then be my reply content.

The info must appear in all my replies.

```vb
'there is a getsignature function before the code.
Public Sub my_reply()
    Dim objOL As Outlook.Application
    Dim objMsg As Object
    Dim objSelection As Outlook.Selection
    Dim objMail As Outlook.mailitem
    Dim StrSignature As String

    StrSignature = GetSignature("C:\Users\xxx\xxx\Microsoft\Signatures\ABC.htm")
    
    Set objOL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set objSelection = objOL.ActiveExplorer.Selection
    For Each objMsg In objSelection
        If objMsg.Class = olMail Then
            objMsg.Categories = "Category A"

            Set myreply = objMsg.Reply
            myreply.To = objMsg.SenderEmailAddress
            myreply.BCC = "xxx@abc" & " ; " & "xxx@abc" 
            myreply.Subject = "XYZ matter" & objMsg.Subject
            myreply.Display
            myreply.HTMLBody = StrSignature & "<br><br>" & objMsg.HTMLBody

Release:
            Set objMsg = Nothing
            Set oExplorer = Nothing

        End If
      
    Next
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Try `Set myreply = objMsg.ReplyAll`

Comment: I tried but it doesn't make any difference. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ReplyAll should get the cc. If you are only concerned about missing text ignore this.

```
Set myReply = objMsg.ReplyAll
```

You are overwriting the initial `myreply.HTMLBody`  with `objMsg.HTMLBody`

```
myreply.HTMLBody = StrSignature & "<br><br>" & objMsg.HTMLBody
```

Instead append to the initial `myreply.HTMLBody`

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub my_replyAll()

'Dim objOL As Outlook.Application
Dim objMsg As Object
Dim objSelection As Selection

'Dim objMail As Outlook.mailitem
Dim myReply As mailitem

Dim StrSignature As String

StrSignature = GetSignature("C:\Users\xxx\xxx\Microsoft\Signatures\ABC.htm")

' Set objOL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
'Set objSelection = objOL.ActiveExplorer.Selection
Set objSelection = ActiveExplorer.Selection

For Each objMsg In objSelection

    If objMsg.Class = olMail Then

        Set myReply = objMsg.ReplyAll

        myReply.To = objMsg.SenderEmailAddress

        myReply.BCC = "xxx@abc" & " ; " & "xxx@abc"

        myReply.Subject = "XYZ matter " & objMsg.Subject

        myReply.Display

        'myReply.HtmlBody = StrSignature & "<br><br>" & objMsg.HtmlBody
        myReply.HtmlBody = StrSignature & "<br><br>" & myReply.HtmlBody

Release:
        Set objMsg = Nothing

    End If

Next

End Sub
```